# MySQL Select and Tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, select, resultset

I am currently learning MySQL for Java to integrate to one of my projects. Main reason behind this is because currently I'm using files to store data, which is causing lag. After speaking to a few people most of them said switching to MySQl rather than files to handle data will fix that issue.
     Anyways, I'm confused on a few things in MySQL and was hoping somebody could answer them for me. Firstly, called the SELECT method, how exactly will that work? If I do something like this:

`ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE PlayerName = "" + name + "';");
res.next();`

Will that get me all the results for tokens db under the name column? If that's the case how would I then get the actual token amount? Also how would I create different databases, for example for the players score, tokens, kills, deaths, etc.

Thank you, and hopefully this wasn't to nooby of a question :P

Comment: A good read on SQL would be a start, then on JDBC. I suggest you try wikipedia to get the basics of both, then perhaps google for JDBC examples. `tokens`, `kills` etc are *tables* not *databases*. A database typically contains several tables, each table is defined to have a number of columns, (e.g amount, name...). A table may contain rows or records of data. Each row having actual values for each of the columns.

Comment: @geert3 So say I want to get the user column of the table, how would I do that? Everywhere I've checked using the SELECT syntax only gets the entire table using *. Also how would I be able to store a ArrayList / List?

Comment: `select t.user from mytable t`. If all your examples use select *, then you didn't pick u a good SQL tutorial. At all.